# React & Typescript how get onClick prop from child to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using react & typescript.

I wonder how i can pass event from parent to child with props.

so is example

**parent.tsx**

```
const ParentComponent: React.FC<ParentProps> = (props) =>  {
   const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState("");

   const getActiveItem = (e: React.MouseEvent, title: string) => {
      setActiveItem(title)
   };

   return (
      <ChildComponent activeItem={activeItem} clickHandler={(e) => getActiveItem(e, 'TITLE')} /> 
   )
}
```

**child.tsx**

```
interface ChildProps {
  activeItem: string;
  clickHandler: () => any;
}


const ChildComponent: React.FC<ChildProps> = (props) =>  {
   return (
      <button onClick={props.clickHandler} /> {props.activeItem} </button>
   )
}
```

and on parent component i'm getting error on clickHandler:

```
Type '(e: any) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how the typings for the click handler should be:

```
interface ChildProps {
  activeItem: string;
  clickHandler: (e:  React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
}
```

You should not use `any` as the type for the parameter, as on click event handler accepts `Event` as the parameter.

Comment: I think you can just type the handler as `React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>`.

Answer (score 1):

In your child prop you give type click handler `clickHandler: () => any;`, it does not expect any params.

But when you give the function in the parent component, you give `e` as a parameter. So they don't match.

You could type your clickHanler : `clickHandler: (e: any) => any;`

But you should probably avoid `any`, and try : `(e: React.MouseEvent) => any`.